# C: "%n" (number of characters read) gets ignored by scanf_s

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read a `string` using `scanf` and get the actual str length and then `realloc` it afterward. I've read that `%n` gives the `number of chars read`, so that's what I need. Visual Studio asks me to use `scanf_s`, where after each string you must specify it's buffer size.

I write:

```
int actual_length;
scanf_s("%[^\n]s%n", str, MAX_STRING_LEN, &actual_length);
printf("actual length = %d\n", actual_length);
```

I get:

```
actual length = -858993460
```

So, when I added this `%n` nothing happened. If I take away just the`%n` it says too many args, if I take away just the `&actual_length` it says too few args. If I take away both the result is the same, obviously.

I tried to google for like 40 mins and I'm stuck. MSDN doesn't say anything specific about scanf_s treating `%n`.

Comment: `"%[^\n]s%n"` --> `"%[^\n]%n"`

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Would you care to add an explanation, please?

Comment: @TheVee In this case `s` is not correct.  `s` is a designation that it isn't  conversion specifier. It is interpreted as a matched character. However, since matching characters do not actually exist, Input will fail at `s`. So `%n` is not interpreted.

Comment: offtopic: i wish every newbie would react so quickly on off-topic questions! Besides: when you got a working answer; you could either ask the person to answer to ... well, write down an answer; or write up an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLUEPIXY answered this question in the comments:

"`%[^\n]s%n`" --> "`%[^\n]%n`"

In this case, `s` is not correct. `s` is a designation that it isn't conversion specifier. It is interpreted as a matched character. However, since matching characters do not actually exist, Input will fail at `s`. So `%n` is not interpreted.